# Aggregate package problem: textgreek, lmodern, and kpfonts

Tags: fonts, packages

```latex
documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textgreek}
%\usepackage[notext,noamsmath,notextcomp]{kpfonts}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\textit{\textGamma\textgamma}

\textbf{\textGamma\textgamma}

\textit{\textbf{\textGamma\textgamma}}

\textbf{\textit{\textGamma\textgamma}}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above MWE as written, I get four Gamma,gamma pairs in (respectively) italic, bold, and (2x) italic+bold, which is what I both expect and want.  I have need (elsewhere in the document being written) for each of the two packages that are commented out.  The good news is that if I uncomment the `lmodern` package (but leave `kpfonts` inactive), the output remains unchanged.

If I uncomment only the `kpfonts` package (leaving `lmodern` inactive), the responses are italic then (3x) bold, the effects of the last two `\textit` are eliminated.  When I uncomment both simultaneously, I get italic followed by (3x) upright+medium weight; no application of `\textit` in the last two, no application of `\textbf` anywhere.

In addition to these variants, I've

- experimented with using `\itshape` and `\bfseries`,
- tried changing the order in which the packages were loaded, and
- applied `\let` (and `\LetLtxMacro`) to the letter macros, to the font modifiers, and to both simultaneously.

**The questions:**  Is there a way to load all of these packages and still allow both `\textit` and `\textbf` to act on the text Greek letters from `textgreek`?  Alternatively, is there one or more better (e.g., more recent) packages to use instead of one (or more) of those I've described?  I realize the latter question is vague, as I haven't specified *why* I need those packages. The reality is that I'm only one author among five, and I don't know what all the others are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As egreg points out in his answer, the problem stems from `\bfdefault` being set differently than is the norm.  A simple work around is `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont`.  I wrote the macro

`\newcommand{\textbx}[1]{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont #1}`

which is then used instead of `\textbf`.

Answer (score 2):

The `textgreek` package by default uses Computer Modern (the Greek fonts by C. Beccari). But `kpfonts` sets `\bfdefault` to `b` rather than the standard `bx`, and there are no `b/it` fonts defined among the Greek `cmr` fonts.

```latex
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/cmr/b/it' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/b/n' instead on input line 17.
```

This explains why you don't get bold italic.

You can fix it by defining the desired font substitutions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[notext,noamsmath,notextcomp]{kpfonts}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{b}{it}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/it}{}%
  \DeclareFontShape{LGR}{cmr}{b}{it}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/it}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\textit{\textGamma\textgamma} (it)

\textbf{\textGamma\textgamma} (bf)

\textit{\textbf{\textGamma\textgamma}} (it,bf)

\textbf{\textit{\textGamma\textgamma}} (bf,it)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great ... so long as lmodern is not invoked.  Loading that package (AFAIK) changes Computer Modern to Latin Modern.  I tried modifying your answer with "lmr" replacing "cmr" (and consulted the lgrlmr.fd file as a sanity check, and added lines for the missing {b}{n}<->{bx}{n} combo), but I get a ```Font Family `LGR+lmr' unknown``` error upon compiling.

Comment: @JohnMcVey With Latin Modern you need no adjustment, as far as I can see. Of course it doesn't make any sense to load *both* `kpfonts` and `lmodern`.

Comment: One reason for both packages is that ```kpfonts``` changes the lowercase greek letters to something I can't stand.  Loading ```lmodern``` converts it back.  But the actual reason goes back to my original statement regarding multiple authors: they each want what they want.

Comment: @JohnMcVey No, there's no good reason for doing that.